# How to read from multi-dimensional arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, api, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do something I've never tried before: reading from APIs, and using the returned values in my website. To do this I need to read from multi-dimensional arrays in PHP.

See below the result I am getting from the API callback, when I run the following lines of code:

```
$tempContents = json_decode($data, true);
echo '<pre'; print_r($tempContents); echo '</pre';
```

Results:

```
Array (
    [data] = Array
    (
        [boards] = Array
        (
            [0] = Array
            (
                [columns] = Array
                (
                    [0] = Array
                    (
                        [title] = Name
                    )
                    [1] = Array
                    (
                        [title] = note
                    )
                    [2] = Array
                    (
                        [title] = notes2
                    )
                    [3] = Array
                    (
                        [title] = Status
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    [account_id] = xxxxxxx 
)
```

So that's great, I can see the information there; however, I'm not sure about how to construct a foreach function to retrieve individual values. For example; the name of the second title value.

Comment: in general, you need either a loop for each level or (if the structure is static), to access the value directly by using array's keys.

Comment: _“I was hoping someone could help explain how to read from multi-dimensional arrays in PHP.”_ - that is something you should really rather consult some sort of beginner’s tutorial on first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in 2 way

using `foreach()` directly:-

```
foreach($tempContents['data']['boards'][0]['columns'] as $title){
    echo $title['title'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Or using `array_column()` along with `foreach()`:

```
$finalArray = array_column($tempContents['data']['boards'][0]['columns'],'title');

foreach($finalArray as $title){
    echo $title.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Sample Output:- https://3v4l.org/4ERqd

Comment: For context, this question was asked regarding accessing the monday,com API. I hope this proves useful to others. The help from this code is still being used today.